# System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Ao compilar minha aplicação recebi esse erro da imagem abaixo, alguém saberia como eu poderia resolver?

Comment: Você está tentando acessar o método de um objeto nulo. Verifique se instanciou-o corretamente.

Comment: Diego, obrigado. eu adicionei essa linha /Processo processo = aplProcesso.consultarPorNProcessoERTeste(new NhibernateHelper().Teste().OpenSession(), ""); e funciona, sem dá o erro, entretanto, dessa forma seria meio grotesca da minha parte, existe uma forma para que eu injete a minha thread com a minha sessão atual, pois criei uma outra de teste.

Comment: Muito obrigado por contribuir com dicas, consegui resolver brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method". O próprio programa responde sua dúvida.

O seu método tenta retornar uma sessão sem ao menos verificar se existe uma instância inicializada, quer dizer, sem ao menos saber se uma sessão foi criada ou não. Você precisa realizar uma checagem de exceção e, somente se existe uma sessão, então retorna-la.

Comment: Marcos, alterei aqui e coloquei Processo processo = aplProcesso.consultarPorNProcessoERTeste(new NhibernateHelper().Teste().OpenSession(), ""); funciona, porém seria uma forma grotesca, queria ver um jeito para o chamar minha sessão para injetar a minha thread.

Comment: Isso é um message chain enorme, evite isso o máximo possível.
Você não poderia utilizar blocos Try/Catch pra verificar se a sessão já foi incializada?

Comment: Consegui resolver brother, valeu pelas dicas